# Remote app, Difference of speed between Win7 and Win8

Tags: java, android, remote-connection

I have developed remote app(remote controller) that controls PC's mouse using Wi-fi connection. Basically, android client connects the java server and send X, Y coordinates to it. I almost finished everything else and I have tested it more and more. However, recently I found that it works smoothly and fast in Win8 (x64) but when I tried in Win7 (x64), it's quite delayed and slow. What's the difference between them ? I used DataInput/OutputStream and didn't use a Thread for server. The server is just worked by while(true).

The point is that the moving of mouse is smooth and fast respond in Win8 but not Win7.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Are you sure that it has nothing to do with other particulars of the windows 7 and 8 devices you are using? maybe the 8 device is just newer

Comment: Thanks to reply. I'm 100% sure there is nothing new. All is same. Same device, same apk file, same server file. Furthermore,  The PC with Win 7 has more higher hardware spec. The only thing I think different is just a windows OS.